# How to prevent mutation of private structures returned by reference

Tags: c++, c++20

I have following code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Foo {
public:
    MyStruct const &getValue() {
        return value;
    }

private:
    MyStruct value{10, 20};
};

int main() {
    Foo foo{};
    auto v = foo.getValue();
    v.a = 42; // compiles! it shouldn't!
}
```

I want to return a reference to private member, but don't allow caller to mutate contents of this reference. Just declaring return type to be `MyStruct const &` is not enough, as it probably defines the reference itself to be const, not the object reference points to. Though, declaring return type as `MyStruct& const` fails with "'const' qualifier may not be applied to a reference". I believe I might be missing something here.

I could have solved that with declaring `MyStruct` with all const fields, but I want to mutate it myself inside my class — only disallow caller to do so.

How is it possible to do so?

Comment: `v` is a copy of your object, use `auto&` to create a reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Just declaring return type to be MyStruct const & is not enough, as it probably defines the reference itself to be const, not the object reference points to.

That's wrong. References can't ever be reassigned anyway. This is the correct way to return a reference to an immutable object. However you actually *copy* the returned object:

```
auto v = foo.getValue();
```

and then modify the copy, which is a valid operation. You can declare `v` as reference

```
auto &v = foo.getValue();
```

to get the expected compiler error. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16ea372c9a3a61d1)

Answer (score 3):

Your wrong assumption is that `auto v` declares a reference. It doesn't, you get a copy of the `MyStruct` returned from `getValue()`.

You can check that original object is not mutated:

```
int main() {
    Foo foo{};
    auto v = foo.getValue();
    v.a = 42; // compiles! it should!
    std::cout << foo.getValue().a; //prints 10
}
```

Declaring `v` as reference type wouldn't compile

```
int main() {
    Foo foo{};
    auto& v = foo.getValue(); // const is deduced by auto
    v.a = 42; // error
}
```